# Hibernate basic resource details needed

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, jakarta-ee

For developing a simple hibernate application, what are the libraries and APIs needed? Obviously J2SE and a SQL database, I know, but, what about others?

Application servers, etc...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need application servers or anything like that. You need the  [hibernate](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.6.0.Final/hibernate-distribution-3.6.0.Final-dist.zip/download) jar-file in your classpath, and the driver for your specific database instance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean for "Hibernate Application".
Anyway, the libraries you need are the Hibernate libraries that you can download from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/

Hibernate does not require any specific application server. You can run Hibernate code from a simple Java application. You need the specific JDBC drivers for your database of choice.
If you use MySql, you can download the drivers from here:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Using an application server (such as JBoss) may be useful if you want to leverage certain enterprise features such as connection pools or monitoring that otherwise should be implemented.

Many projects use Hibernate along with the Spring framework to simplify the creation of a Web application.